# (React navigation wix with Redux) App is crashing on start

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, redux-persist

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.54.4

I am trying to implement wix naviagation with redux.
The app is crashing on start. Tried many changes but finally gives error.

https://github.com/aditya21/react_native_basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming that you're using IOS*

It is clearly mentioned in the docs

[**IOS**](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-ios)

> In Xcode, you will need to edit this file: **AppDelegate.m**. This function is the main entry point for your app:

Here's the link to the edited file [AppDelegate.m](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/example/ios/example/AppDelegate.m)

Here's are the links for the [android setup](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android)

Comment: After this you'll see `crash` with the `redux store` that you're using. For that you can post a separate question or resolve it.

Comment: Thanks Pritish. I did the changes as you recommended. After that I got error on store.getState(). I have resolved it and the app is running now.